# Populating Data in a view after an http call

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that needs to display data that is fetched via an asynchronous http call to another server.

[image]

I have a service that fetches the data. It gets instantiated immediately, but the http call takes a few seconds to return. When it does, the page is already drawn and found errors for missing data.

In the ngOnInit() method of the component, I am attempting to fetch the data that is obviously not there yet.

What is the best/proper approach to fill in the data? is it to add a listener to the http response and then populate the component or is there another standard approach?

Thanks
I know I can add listeners in the component to subscribe to change events, but I'm wondering what the more correct approach is here.

Comment: Can you post bit of code also?

Comment: You should have data before the page load, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper approach  for this would be to use the `async` pipe.

Your .ts component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private service:Service){}
   apiData$:any;
   ngOnInit() {
      apiData$ = thhis.service.getData();
   }
}
```

And then in your .html component, you use the `async` pipe.

```
<div>{{apiData$|async}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the component when you receive the data.
I do that usually in the end of the call method.